# Devolver lista de una funcion

Tags: python

Quiero hacer una funcion que me devuelva en una lista la cuenta atrás de un numero pasado por referencia y en caso de ser 0 que devuelva unicamente una lista con el numero, quisiera conocer una forma mejor de indicar ese return en base a la variable miLista

Ejemplo: cuenta_atras(4) -> [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

```
def cuenta_atras(num):
  miLista=[]
  if num == 0:
    return [0]
```

Answer (score 3):

La función `range(inicio, fin, paso)` tiene tres parámetros, lo que permite generar secuencias ascendentes y descendentes.

Con `range(4, -1, -1)` obtengo la secuencia `4, 3, 2, 1, 0`: Se inicia en 4 y avanza en pasos de -1 (retrocede), hasta llegar al valor final, -1. Con la función `list`, transformo esa secuencia en una lista.

La función se reduce a:

```
def cuenta_atras(n):
    return list(range(n, -1, -1))
```

**Demo**

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i, cuenta_atras(i))
```

produce

```
0 [0]
1 [1, 0]
2 [2, 1, 0]
3 [3, 2, 1, 0]
4 [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
5 [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
6 [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
7 [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
8 [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
9 [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que deberías regresar la lista

```
def cuenta_atras(num):
    miLista=[x for x in range(num,0,-1)] #lo hago como ejemplo, vos usas el método que elijas
    if num == 0:
        miLista=[0]  #asigno a la lista el valor 0
    
    #sin importar el número ingresado regresamos la lista 
    return miLista   
print(cuenta_atras(6))
print(cuenta_atras(0))
```

Comment: La cuenta no llega a cero si `num > 0`.

Comment: Para que la cuenta llegue a 0, puedes cambiar el segundo argumento de `range` a -1.

Comment: Otra cosa que podrías hacer es en lugar de hacer una lista comprimida, convertir el rango en una lista con `list(range(num, -1, -1))`